# Is it possible to reverse the x and y axis of the mouse on Android?

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, apk, mouse

Good day!

Is it possible to reverse the x and y axis of the mouse such that when I hover the mouse to the right, the cursor will go to the left? I'm using a generic bluetooth mouse that I found on ebay. I already searched the web and all I found was on Windows, OSX, and Linux. I'm thinking of using Sakasa App and convert it to apk but I highly doubt that it'll work. Thank you so much! :)

P.S Sorry for my grammar if there's any.

Comment: 1. you can't convert the application to APK. it does not work this way. 2. You should be able somehow to reverse it, but you will need to edit the mouse driver for example, or at least get root access.

Comment: Thank you for replying @VladMatvienko! Well, I already have root access to my phone. However, I don't know where to start. I'll try to surf again in the internet about the mouse driver.

Comment: if you have root, then you might be able to use some linux instructions. But you can't use 3rd party linux software on Android, only the standard one, and even not all since Android is not full linux

Comment: Did you solve it ? @JohnSpencerSchimdt